# css justify with flexbox (no table): fill empty space with dots

Tags: css, flexbox, clip, justify

I'm using php to generate a menu from a mysql database.
In my design it's not possible to use a html table so I use an unnumbered list .
Now i have 3 vars: **dishname**, **short_description** and the **price**.

Between the [dishname (short_description)].................[price] need to be flexible dots;

In this screenshot you can see what I have now:

[image: what I have now]

html:

```
<ul>
<li class=dish>
<div>
<a class=dish>...</a>
<span class=short>...</span>
</div>
<span class=price>..€</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.submenu li{ line-height:1.6rem; margin-left: 2rem; list-style-type: circle; text-transform: lowercase; width: 100%;}
li.dish{ display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }
li.dish span.short::after{ position: absolute; z-index: -1; content: "....................................................................................................................................";}
span.short{ font-size: 0.8rem; font-style: italic;}
span.price{ font-size: 1rem;  }
```

In the screenshot you can see what the problem is, the "................." should be clipped or responsive to the available space in the width. There should be no dots visible after the price.

Comment: You forgot to add `width` and `overflow: hidden`. It would be great to have a [mre].

Comment: the `width:100%;` is in the `ul.submenu li` and I tried to put an `overflow: hidden;` there too, but it doesn't do the trick unfortunately. I'll try to make the MRE... Where should I put the `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you would not use the "....." as a content in the after but you make it fill up all the available space an use a border bottom in the after something like this:

```css
ul.submenu li {
    line-height: 1.6rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    list-style-type: circle;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    width: 100%;
}
li.dish {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
li.dish > div {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
li.dish span.short::after {
    content: " ";
    flex: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
span.short {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}
span.price {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class=dish>
    <div> <a class=dish>Dish 1</a><span class=short>(Vis, Pastfdafdasa)</span></div>
    <span class=price>€</span>
  </li>
  
  <li class=dish>
    <div> <a class=dish>Dish 2</a><span class=short>(Vis, Pastcx\zc\xzcx\za)</span></div>
    <span class=price>€</span>
  </li>
  
  <li class=dish>
    <div> <a class=dish>Dish 3</a><span class=short>(Vis, Pastaczczcxz\cx\z)</span></div>
    <span class=price>€</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This way you can make it responsive as well.
If you want to move the dots up or down you can add margins to the `li.dish span.short::after`

Comment: you are a genius! thanks to be constructive, problem solved! no thanks to all the -1 trolls.

Comment: The -1 as are because the question is not formatted properly. Try to use the code snippet  
 functionality the feature and you will get answers fasters as well.